# ASP.Net C# #if/endif (how to use)

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

Following this article ([ASP.Net Core 2.1 Razor pages)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-2.1)) I have run into a problem with my code.
Upon visiting the GitHub repos for the Student\Student.cshtml.cs page, the author has uploaded a page full of #if/#endif statements, but has not explained (in the article) how these are used. ([Here is the sample doc](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/data/ef-rp/intro/samples/cu21/Pages/Students/Index.cshtml.cs))

An the only links that are return on a search, appear to point me back to Miscrosoft.com. (Despite visiting many of the links, I am still at a loss for how these work - saying lots of stuff without actually saying anything seems to be a Microsoft trend)

What I have found implies that the #If/#endif statements are looking for values that have been defined in a configuration file somewhere? But the sample code makes no (blatantly obvious to me) reference to a config file.

Could you talk me through how this sample code works?
I want to ensure that I can eliminate the #if/#Endif statements as possible cause for my issues.
Thanks

Comment: You can have a read of this: [#if preprocessor directive in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if)

Comment: Been there. That's what led me to think that its looking for parameters in a config file. Is the #if/Endif evaluated when I BUILD my solution, or is it evaluated when my built/published solution runs? It seems to be the former, and I would need it to be the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#if` and `#endif` are C# preprocessor directives. C# Preprocessor Directives are used to help in conditional compilation.

If the case of the source code you linked to, [line 29](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/be93b1acb306446b4b43e7c043e69d316661ed57/aspnetcore/data/ef-rp/intro/samples/cu21/Pages/Students/Index.cshtml.cs#L29) has `#if SortFilterPage`, and an `#else` on [line 33](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/be93b1acb306446b4b43e7c043e69d316661ed57/aspnetcore/data/ef-rp/intro/samples/cu21/Pages/Students/Index.cshtml.cs#L33), and `#endif` on [line 35](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/be93b1acb306446b4b43e7c043e69d316661ed57/aspnetcore/data/ef-rp/intro/samples/cu21/Pages/Students/Index.cshtml.cs#L35). Line 29 means if `SortFilterPage` is defined, then the compilation will include lines 30 to 32, and not include line 34. Similarly, the compiled code will include lines from line 117 to 168.

On the other hand, if `SortFilterPage` was not defined during compilation, then lines 30 to to 32 will not be included for compilation, and so are lines 117 to 168, but line 34 will be.

As you would notice, `SortFilterPage` is actually defined in the source code by the `#define` directive at [line 1](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/be93b1acb306446b4b43e7c043e69d316661ed57/aspnetcore/data/ef-rp/intro/samples/cu21/Pages/Students/Index.cshtml.cs#L1). But you could remove that definition, and instead define it when you run the compilation using the [command line build tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe).

You could change line 1 to instead have `#define SortFilter`. This would mean that `SortFilterPage` would be undefined (assuming it was not defined at compilation via the command line tool). In that case, it would have changed which lines are included for compilation. For example, lines 81 to 114 would be included in the compiled code.

Further readings:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/C-Sharp-language-preprocessor-directives/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe

Comment: Thanks Frank...This is a most informative answer. Much appreciated.